# F# Instance Methods... should they return a new instance instead of altering the current object?

Tags: f#, immutability

The problem is whether an instance method should in anyway alter the object that contains the method or should it return a new instance?  I'm new to F# and the concept of full mmutability that is suggested for F#.

Just using psuedo code for now unless I need to be more specific.

First thought is just add the message to the message list on the object:

```
class Something
  ctr(messages)
     _messages.Add(messages)

  AddMessage(message)
   _messages.Add(message)
```

Second is to construct a new list that joins the old list and the new message.  Then I would create a new instance altogther and send back.

```
class Something
  ctr(messages)
     _messages.Add(messages)

  AddMessage(message)
    newMessageList = _messages.Join(message)
      return new Something(newMessageList)
```

Am I overthinking immutability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are doing "class based" programming which is one of the way (rather unfortunate) to do object oriented programming, you would be doing in place state modification rather than returning a new state (as that's what would be expected when you are doing OO).

In case you really want to go towards immutability then I would suggest you need to use more FP concepts like Modules, Functions (not methods which have you have in class based programming), recursive data types etc.

My answer is way too general and the appropriate answer lies in the fact that how this class of your will fit in the big picture of your application design.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the answer depends on your requirements.  The immutable style is probably more idiomatic, and would be a sensible default.  However, one nice thing about F# is that you can choose what to do based on your needs; there's nothing inherently wrong with code that uses mutation.  Here are some things to consider:

- Sometimes the mutable approach leads to better performance, particularly when used in a single-threaded context (but make sure to measure realistic scenarios to be sure!)
- Sometimes the immutable approach lends itself better to use in multi-threaded scenarios
- Sometimes you want to interface with libraries that are easier to use with imperitave code (e.g. an API taking a `System.Action<_>`).
- Are you working on a team?  If so, are they experienced C# developers?  Experienced F# developers?  What kind of code would they find easiest to read (perhaps the mutable style)?  What kind of code will you find easiest to maintain (probably the immutable style)?
- Are you just doing this as an exercise?  Then practicing the immutable style may be worthwhile.

Stepping back even further, there are a few other points to consider:

- Do you really even need an instance method?  Often, using a let-bound function in a module is more idiomatic.
- Do you really even need a new nominal type for what you're doing?  If it's just a thin wrapper around a list, you might consider just using `list`s directly.